# Can we use va_arg with unions?

Tags: c, variadic-functions, language-lawyer, unions

6.7.2.1 paragraph 14 of my draft of the C99 standard has this to say about unions and pointers (emphasis, as always, added):

> The size of a union is sufﬁcient to contain the largest of its members. The value of at 
>   most one of the members can be stored in a union object at any time. **A pointer to a 
>   union object, suitably converted, points to each of its members (or if a member is a bit- 
>   field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa.**

All well and good, that means that it is legal to do something like the following to copy either a signed or unsigned int into a union, assuming we only want to copy it out into data of the same type:

```
union ints { int i; unsigned u; };

int i = 4;
union ints is = *(union ints *)&i;
int j = is.i; // legal
unsigned k = is.u; // not so much
```

7.15.1.1 paragraph 2 has this to say:

> The `va_arg` macro expands to an expression that has the speciﬁed type and the value of 
>   the next argument in the call. The parameter `ap` shall have been initialized by the 
>   `va_start` or `va_copy` macro (without an intervening invocation of the `va_end`  macro for the sameap). Each invocation of the `va_arg` macro modifies `ap` so that the values of successive arguments are returned in turn. The parameter `type` shall be a type name speciﬁed such that the type of a pointer to an object that has the speciﬁed type can be obtained simply by postfixing a `*` to `type`. If there is no actual next argument, **or if type is not compatible with the type of the actual next argument (as promoted according to the default argument promotions),** the behavior is undefined, except for the following cases:
>
> **—one type is a signed integer type, the other type is the corresponding unsigned integer 
>   type, and the value is representable in both types;**
>
> —one type is pointer to void and the other is a pointer to a character type.

I'm not going to go and cite the part about default argument promotions. My question is: is this defined behavior:

```
void func(int i, ...)
{
    va_list arg;
    va_start(arg, i);
    union ints is = va_arg(arg, union ints);
    va_end(arg);
}

int main(void)
{
    func(0, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

If so, it would appear to be a neat trick to overcome the "and the value is compatible with both types" requirement of signed/unsigned integer conversion (albeit in a way that's rather difficult to do anything with legally). If not, it would appear to be safe to just use `unsigned` in this case, but what if there were more elements in the `union` with more incompatible types? If we can guarantee that we won't access the union by element (i.e. we just copy it into another `union` or storage space that we're treating like a `union`) and that all elements of the union are the same size, is this allowed with varargs? Or would it only be allowed with pointers?

In practice I expect this code will almost never fail, but I want to know if it's defined behavior. My current guess is that it appears not to be defined, but that seems incredibly dumb.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I suppose I'm more interested in whether `func(0, -1); func(0, UINT_MAX);` is legal. `func(0, 1)` might be legal solely because 1 fits into both `int` and `unsigned`.

Comment: `unsigned k = is.u;` is legal in C99.

Comment: @Dietrich - Is there an exception due to the signed/unsigned thing?

Comment: None of those calls passes a union. You'd presumably need a compound literal: `func(1, (union ints) { .i = 0 }); func(2, (union ints) { .u = UINT_MAX });`, etc.  Or union variables.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: As Pascal Cuoq notes, it became legal in C99 TC3 to do *arbitrary* type punning through unions.  The resulting values are undefined.

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple things off.

> A pointer to a union object, suitably converted, points to each of its members (or if a member is a bit- field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa.

This does not mean that the types are compatible.  In fact, they are not compatible.  So the following code is wrong:

```
func(0, 1); // undefined behavior
```

If you want to pass a union,

```
func(0, (union ints){ .u = BLAH });
```

You can check by writing the code,

```
union ints x;
x = 1;
```

GCC gives an "error: incompatible types in assignment" message when compiling.

However, most implementations will "probably" do the right thing in both cases.  There are some other problems...

```
union ints {
    int i;
    unsigned u;
};

int i = 4;
union ints is = *(union ints *)&i; // Invalid
int j = is.i; // legal
unsigned k = is.u; // also legal (see note)
```

The behavior when you dereference the address of a type using a type other than its actual type `*(uinon ints *)&i` is sometimes undefined (looking up the reference, but I'm pretty sure about this).  However, in C99 it is permitted to access a union member other than the most recently stored union member (or is it C1x?), but the value is implementation defined and may be a trap representation.

**About type punning through unions:** As Pascal Cuoq notes, it's actually TC3 that defines the behavior of accessing a union element other than the most recently stored one.  TC3 is the third update to C99.  The good news is that this part of TC3 is really codifying existing practice — so think of it as a de facto part of C prior to TC3.

Comment: TC3 makes it explicit that unions can be used for type punning in C99: Defect Report 283 http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_283.htm

Answer (score 2):

Since the standard says:

> The parameter type shall be a type name speciﬁed such that the type of a pointer to an object that has the speciﬁed type can be obtained simply by postfixing a * to type.

For `union ints`, that condition is satisfied.  Since `union ints *` is a perfectly good representation of a pointer to a `union ints`, so there is nothing in that sentence to prevent it being used to collect a value pushed onto the stack as a union.

If you cheat and try to pass a plain `int` or `unsigned int` in place of a union, then you would be invoking undefined behaviour.  Thus, you could use:

```
union ints u1 = ...;

func(0, (union ints) { .i = 0 });
func(1, (union ints) { .u = UINT_MAX });
func(2, u1);
```

You could not use:

```
func(1, 0);
```

The arguments are not union types.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you think that code should never fail in practice. It would fail on any implementation where integer types are passed by register but aggregate types (even when small) are passed on the stack, and I see nothing in the standard that forbids such implementations. A union containing an `int` is not a type compatible with `int`, even if their sizes are the same.

Back to your first code fragment, it has a problem too:

```
union ints is = *(union ints *)&i;
```

This is an aliasing violation and invokes undefined behavior. You could avoid it by using `memcpy` and I suppose then it would be legal..

I'm also a bit confused about your comment here:

```
unsigned k = is.u; // not so much
```

Since the value 4 is represented in both the signed and unsigned types, this should be legal, unless it's specifically forbidden as a special case.

If this doesn't answer your question, perhaps you could elaborate more on what (albeit theoretical) problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Can you expand on how this is an aliasing violation?

Comment: You first access the object through an lvalue of type `int` then through one of type `union ints`. The compiler may assume they do not alias one another.

Comment: Is the compiler allowed to assume `restrict` on parameters passed in place of ellipsis (`...`).

Comment: How could the compiler assume that varargs arguments are passed in different places based on what type they are?

Comment: The only place I find "alias" that looks relevant is in a footnote to 6.5 p 7: "An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types: ... - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members".  Is there some other prohibition you meant?

Comment: @wnoise: I don't think that could possibly mean what you think it means. If it did, accessing an `int` through a pointer to `union { int i; char b[HUGE]; }` to copy the whole union type would be valid, even though it obviously would read past the end of the object...

Comment: @Chris: I've got news for you. It does, on basically any arch but x86. On x86_64 for example, integers and pointers get passed in general purpose registers, float and double in sse registers, and structures split between registers if they fit, or otherwise on the stack. The amount of bloat the compiler has to generate in `va_start`/`va_arg` to support this is disgusting, and basically the people designing the ABI did it just so that `int main() { printf("hello, world\n"); }` (without including stdio.h) would work...

Comment: Yeah, I agree it shouldn't be kosher, but I don't think "aliasing violation" is the best way to describe the problem with it, and I'm trying to figure out why do think that.

Comment: @R.. - That's kind of disgusting. If that's the case, how come `printf("%s %i", 1, "this");` doesn't end up working? Wouldn't it just look for the string and the integer in different places, and find them each there in the place they're expected to be?

Comment: No, both integers (of any size) and pointers are passed in general-purpose registers. Try `printf("%d %f", 1.0, 2);` and see what happens, though... ;-) This is the reason why passing wrong arguments to a variadic function has to be undefined behavior, and not simply some sort of reinterpretation of the representation.