# Does endianess matter when reading N bits from unsigned char

Tags: c, endianness

I am trying to read a sequence of bits received from network (in a pre-defined format) and was wondering do we have to take care of endianees.

For example, the pre-defined format says that starting from most significant bit the data received would look like this

```
 |R||  11 bits data||20 bits data||16 bits data| where R is reserved and ignored.
```

My questions is while extracting do I have to take care of endianess or can I just do

```
u16 first_11_bits = *(u16 *)data & 0x7FF0) >>4
u32 20_bits_data  = *(u32 *)data & 0x000FFFFF)
```

Comment: You need to use `&` for masking, not `&&`.

Comment: Those `&&`s probably won't do what you think they will.  They're the "logical and" operators, not the bitwise and ("`&`").

Comment: i would say yes. what if you send a number from a little endian machine and recieve it on a big endian and vice versa. normally the sent data should be in the big endian format

Comment: We need more context.  How did `data` arrive?  Did it look like `uint8_t data[MAX_LEN]; read(fd, data, sizeof(data);` ?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of network? IP is defined in terms of bytes so whatever order the bit stream happens to be in the underlying layers has been abstracted away from you and you receive the bits in the order that your CPU understands them. Which means that the abstraction that C provides you to access those bits is portable. Think in terms of shifting left or right in C. Whatever the endianness is in the CPU the direction and semantics of shifting in C doesn't change.

So the question is: how is the data encoded into a byte stream by the other end? However the other end encodes the data should be the way you decode it. If they just shove bits into one byte and send that byte over the network, then you don't need to care. If they put bits into one int16 and then send it in network byte order, then you need to worry endianness of that int16. If they put the bits into an int32 and send that, then you need to worry about endianness of that int32.

Answer (score 0):

```
u16 first_11_bits = *(u16 *)data & 0x7FF0) >>4
u32 20_bits_data  = *(u32 *)data & 0x000FFFFF)
```

This is [UB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630180/721269). Either `data` points to a `u16` or it points to a `u32`. It can't point to both. This isn't an endianess issue, it's just an invalid access. You must access for read through the same pointer type you accessed for write. Whichever way you wrote it, that's how you read it. Then you can do bit operations on the value you read back, which will be the same as the value you wrote.

One way this can go wrong is that the compiler is free to assume that a write through a `u32 *` won't affect a value read through a `u16 *`. So the write may be to memory but the read may be from a value cached in a register. This has broken real-world code.

For example:

```
u16 i = * (u16 *) data;
* (u32 *) data = 0;
u16 j = * (u16 *) data;
```

The compiler is free to treat the last line as `u16 j = i;`. It last read `i` the very same way, and it is free to assume that a write to a `u32 *` can't affect the result of a read from a `u16 *`.

Comment: Hi David,I am not sure I follow. "Whichever way you wrote it, that's how you read it." I don't know how it was written. The bit stream is something I receive over air and I have to decode the bit stream in a pre-defined format.The received bits are always byte aligned. Can I do the following : u32 first_32_bits = *(u32*)data; first_11_bits = (first_32_bits & 0x7FF0)>>4; 20_bits_data = first_32_bits & 0x000FFFFF

Comment: It depends how you wrote it. If you wrote it as a `u32`, then you must read it that way. If not, not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will always need to worry about endianness when reading/writing to external resource (file, network, ...). But it has nothing to do with the bit operations.

Casting directly `(u16 *)data` is not portable way to do things.

I recommend having functions to convert data to native types, before doing bit operations.